# Regarding issue with the jquery autocomplete concatenation with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get value from two fields using the jQuery autocomplete with PHP, but I am not able to able to get the data.

index.php:

```
var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
$("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

The above code will get the value from the `autocomplete.php` file which is:

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT account_name from account";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$dname_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dname_list[] = $row['account_name'];
}
echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the JSON string output by `autocomplete.php` directly in your JS code, use the AJAX features of the autocomplete plugin by providing the string URL of the PHP page to the `source` property:

```
$("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: 'autocomplete.php',
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx for your feedback rory. i have solve this problem my own. just created the json array as accordingly.

Comment: by using the php array functions.